# GLM object in R takes more RAM than the object size of the GLM object

Tags: r, ram, glm, objectsize

I am trying to save multiple GLM objects in a list. One GLM object is trained on a large dataset, but the size of the object is reduces by setting NULL all the unnecessary data in the GLM object. The problem is that I get RAM issues because R reserves much more RAM than the size of the GLM object. Does someone know why this problem occur and how I can solve this? Behind this saving the object results in a larger file than the object size.

Example:

```
> glm_full <- glm(formula = formule , data = dataset, family = binomial(), model = F, y = F)
> glm_full$data <- glm_full$model <- glm_full$residuals <- glm_full$fitted.values <- glm_full$effects <- glm_full$qr$qr <- glm_full$linear.predictors <- glm_full$weights <- glm_full$prior.weights <- glm_full$y <- NULL
> rm(list= ls()[!(ls() %in% c('glm_full'))])
> object.size(glm_full)
172040 bytes
> gc()
           used  (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells   944802  50.5    3677981  196.5   3862545  206.3
Vcells 83600126 637.9  503881514 3844.4 629722059 4804.4
> rm(glm_full)
> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells  944208 50.5    2942384  157.2   3862545  206.3
Vcells 4474439 34.2  403105211 3075.5 629722059 4804.4
```

Here you can see that R reserves RAM for the GLM object, saving multiple GLM objects in the environment results in out of RAM problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rough explanation for this is that `glm` hides pointers to the environment and things from the environment deep down inside of the `glm` object (and in numerous places).

What do you need to be able to do with your `glm`? Even though you've nulled out a lot of the "fat" of the model, your object size will still grow linearly with your data size, and when you compound that by storing multiple `glm` objects, bumping up against RAM limitations is an obvious concern.

Here is a function that will allow you to slice away pretty much everything that is non-essential, and the best part is that the `glm` object size will remain constant regardless of how large your data gets.

```
stripGlmLR = function(cm) {
  cm$y = c()
  cm$model = c()

  cm$residuals = c()
  cm$fitted.values = c()
  cm$effects = c()
  cm$qr$qr = c()  
  cm$linear.predictors = c()
  cm$weights = c()
  cm$prior.weights = c()
  cm$data = c()


  cm$family$variance = c()
  cm$family$dev.resids = c()
  cm$family$aic = c()
  cm$family$validmu = c()
  cm$family$simulate = c()
  attr(cm$terms,".Environment") = c()
  attr(cm$formula,".Environment") = c()

  cm
}
```

Some notes:

You can null out `model$family` entirely and the `predict` function will still return its default value (so, `predict(model, newdata = data))` will work). However, `predict(model, newdata=data, type = 'response')` will fail. You can recover the `response` by passing the link value through the inverse link function: in the case of logistic regression, this is the sigmoid function, `sigmoid(x) = 1/(1 + exp(-x))`. (not sure about `type = 'terms'`)

Most importantly, any of the other things besides `predict` that you might like to do with a `glm` model will fail on the stripped-down version (so `summary()`, `anova()`, and `step()` are all a no-go). Thus, you'd be wise  to extract all of this info from your `glm` object and then running the `stripGlmLR` function.

CREDIT: [Nina Zumel](http://ninazumel.com/) for an awesome analysis on `glm` object memory allocation

Comment: Thanks for you help, this solved the problem perfectly!